# how to make the text view update the input of the selected date and time picker

Tags: android, onclick, datepicker, textview

i have a simple android application that allow user to select a date and time using the date and picker an the result will be displayed in the text view but the problem is that the text view just display zeros how to fix this error ????

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.datetime;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // btn1=time btn2=date
    Button btn1, btn2;
    TextView txtv;
    int year;
    int monthofyear;
    int dayofmonth;
    int hourofday;
    int minute;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dt = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tpd;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

        dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthofyear,
                    int dayofmonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthofyear);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayofmonth);
                updateText();

            }

            public void updateText() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                txtv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
                        .append(monthofyear).append(dayofmonth));

            }

        };
        tpd = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofday, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourofday);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                updateText();

            }

            public void updateText() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                txtv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hourofday).append(
                        minute));
            }

        };

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {

            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dpd,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONDAY)).show();

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, tpd,
                    cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    false).show();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies in the click listener of button click. You have written **MONDAY** instead of **DAY_OF_MONTH**

But use my code :-

```
package com.example.datetimepicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button date,time;
    TextView preview;
    int year,monthofyear,dayofmonth,hourofday,minute;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dt = DateFormat.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tpd;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,dpd,
                        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            }
        });
        time = (Button)findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,tpd,
                        cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        false).show();
            }
        });
        preview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                preview.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year+"/")
                        .append(monthOfYear+"/").append(dayOfMonth));
            }
        };

        tpd = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hourofday, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourofday);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                preview.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hourofday+"/")
                        .append(minute));
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: ok i changed the Monday but still giving zeros how to fix it ?

Comment: Dude , use my code. It is working correctly. Date and time are showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized you variable that why your textview is not updated.there need small modification in your code.

```
     dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthofyear,
                int dayofmonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthofyear);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayofmonth);
            updateText(year,monthofyear,dayofmonth);

        }

        public void updateText( int year,
        int monthofyear,
        int dayofmonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
                    .append(monthofyear).append(dayofmonth));

        }

    };
```

remove your int variables ,they not needed.